# how to select first link in a parent list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery accordion, and need to remove the href attribute from the parent li.  I only need to remove it from JUST the parent li - not the children.

```
var parent = $("#quicklaunch ul > li:has('ul')");
parent.find("span.menu-item-text:first").append("&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class='fa fa-angle-down' aria-hidden='true'></i>");
parent.find("a:first").removeAttr("href").css("cursor", "pointer");
```

the current code works, but only if the parent list item has a link.  if it doesn't, it goes down to the children and then removes that link.  i want that link to stay.  what's the correct selector?

EDIT TO ADD:  I was able to use has("a"), but the removeAttr selector is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `children()` to avoid looking inside the `<ul>`

```
parent.children("a").removeAttr("href").css("cursor", "pointer");
```

Comment: oops, nm... in the fiddle the a was a child of span, not a direct descendant of the parent variable which is why the removeAttr didn't work.  changed it & this worked like a charm.  thanks!